# strtotime() in php returning always 01-01-1970

Tags: php

I am using a variable to get the date from the database,then i am passing that variable to strtotime function to get the desired format,but it always returning wrong date.perhaps there is a problem in passing a variable in strtotime function.please suggest me guys,how should i get the correct date in correct format.

Here is what i am trying to do

```
 $date = $fetch_user['date'];
 $newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date));
 $day = date('l', strtotime($newDate));

 echo $newDate;
 echo "-----";
 echo $day;
 exit;
```

Comment: what is your $fetch_user['date']

Comment: which php version you are usiing ?

Comment: can you post the value of  $date?

Comment: what $fetch_user['date'] holds? may i know the exact value?

Comment: You're using `strtotime()` two times, but the second time, you're feeding it the result of the first. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: check this link http://3v4l.org/C05Dr it is working properly

Comment: if your php version is less than 5.1.3 you get this problem

Answer (score 2):

January 1, 1970 is the so called Unix epoch. It's the date where they started counting the Unix time. If you get this date as a return value, it usually means that the conversion of your date to the Unix timestamp returned a (near-) zero result. So the date conversion doesn't succeed. Most likely because it receives a wrong input.

In other words, your `strtotime($date)` returns 0, meaning that $date is passed in an unsupported format for the strtotime function.

So you'll have to check for yourself `$date`, before calling strtotime at all.

Comment: $date is returning a valid date other than January 1, 1970,but still its not working.when i use a date as a string,its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

01-01-1970 means you probably get 0 as a result of `strtotime()`. You are probably using a format, that this function cannot understand. The PHP documentation states:

> The function expects to be given a string containing an English date
>   format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp (the
>   number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC), relative to the
>   timestamp given in now, or the current time if now is not supplied.

So it is not really flexible. You might want to try `DateTime::createFromFormat` instead. Take a look at it's [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Basically you have to specify the format of the date string, that you give as an input as well. That way you can use whatever date format you want.

Example from php.net:

```
<?php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', '15-Feb-2009');
```